# How to compute $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

> Does
>
> $$p=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)$$
>
> have any closed form in terms of known mathematical constants? The computer says 
>   $$p=3.682154\dots$$
>   but I don't even know how do devise the converging upper and lower bounds to obtain this result.

---

edit Jan. 15: I've got rid of the infinite product in favor of an fastly converging infinite sum over finite products [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460579/how-to-compute-prod-n-1-infty-left1-frac1n-right/1102603#1102603).

---

Thoughts:

$$p=\lim_{n\to \infty}p_n\hspace{.7cm}\text{where}\hspace{.7cm} p_n=p_{n-1}\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)\hspace{.7cm}\text{with}\hspace{.7cm} p_1=2.$$

So I looked for an emerging pattern

$p_1=(1+\frac{1}{1!})$

$p_2=(1+\frac{1}{1!})(1+\frac{1}{2!})=(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!})+(\frac{1}{1!2!})$

$p_3=((1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!})+\frac{1}{1!2!})(1+\frac{1}{3!})
=(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!})+(\frac{1}{1!2!}+\frac{1}{1!3!}+\frac{1}{2!3!})+\frac{1}{1!2!3!}$

It appears that

$$p=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{nm}$$

where $a_{1m}$ is the sum of terms with *one* inverse $\frac{1}{m!}$, and then $a_{2m}$ is the sum of (sums of) terms with *two* inverses $\frac{1}{r!s!}$. For example the term $\frac{1}{1!3!}$ is in the sum, and so I guess I need all the partitions into $n$ numbers. However, we don't want to count $\frac{1}{2!2!}$ and so it's more complicated. I guess the product can be written as a sum of term $(e-1)^n$ minus something, as for example

$(e-1)^2 
= \left(\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}+ \frac{1}{3!}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}+ \frac{1}{3!}+\cdots\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{  m!\,n!}$.

The logarithm of it is also a sum of sums which somewhat resembles the series expansion of the exponential function, but there, I think, the coefficients are powers of $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: It might be easier to compute $\prod (1+\frac{z^n}{n!})$, which should be $\sum \frac{1}{m!} P_m z^m$ where $P_m$ is the number of equivalence relations on a set of $m$ elements into classes of different sizes.

Comment: I didn't mean "easier" in any pragmatic sense, just that an exponential generating function might be a useful approach to get some upper and lower bounds. As you can see, this function of $z$ counts something. It's not clear to me what use that might be.

Comment: For a reference about the generating function check out page 137 of Phillip Flajolet's http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html Analytic Combinatorics,  entry II.26

Comment: The ISC http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/ finds this number only in terms of various infinite products.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A238695 for $n\geq0$

Comment: What exactly is a known mathematical constant?

Comment: Here is an identity which may be helpful: $ \frac{1}{0!n!} + \frac{1}{1!(n-1)!} +\frac{1}{2!(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{3!(n-3)!}...+\frac{1}{(n-1)!1!} +\frac{1}{n!0!}= \frac{2^n}{n!} $

Comment: if you take the log of this expression you get a sum of the form $\log(1 + 1) + \log(1 + 1) + \log(1 + \frac{1}{2}) + ... $ and these logs can be expanded via the taylor series @ x= 0 for $\log(1+x)$, then recollecting terms you can use hypergeometric results such as from this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327929995_An_identity_for_the_infinite_sum_sum_n0inftyfrac1n3/link/5bada41b45851574f7ebde60/download to restate the log-sum. It will contain an $e$ an a bessel function value but after that its just strange hypergeometric expressions

Answer (score 18):

Just one observation $$\ln p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=e-1$$ Since $$\ln (1+x)-x< 0$$ for all $x> 0$. So, $$p<e^{e-1}\approx 5.5749\ldots$$

**Additional Observation:** A tighter lower and upper bound comes as below:

$$\ln p=\sum_{n\ge 1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)=\ln 2+\sum_{n\ge 2}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(n!)^k}\\ $$ Then using the inequality $$\left(\sum_{i}a_i^k\right)\le \left(\sum_{i}a_i\right)^k$$ for $a_i\ge 0$, we get (after some calculations, which is not very difficult)$$\ln 2+e-2+\frac{1}{2}\ln (1-(e-2)^2)<\ln p<\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{e-1}{3-e}\right)\\ \Rightarrow 2e^{e-2}\sqrt{4e-e^2-3}<p<2\sqrt{\frac{e-1}{3-e}}\\ \Rightarrow 2.8538\ldots <p< 4.9393\ldots$$

Answer (score 8):

Note:  Steven Stadnicki made a good point
about the not-so-good convergence 
of my suggested computationa; method.
I am modifying this to try to correct this.

Expanding Samrat's observation,
for any positive integer $m$,

$\begin{align}
\ln p
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)+\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)\\
&= G_m+F_m\\
\text{where}\\
F_m &=\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(n!)^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(n!)^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^k}\\
\end{align}
$

Let $f_m(k) = \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^k}
$,
so
$F_m = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} f_m(k)
$.

$f_m(1)$ is $e$ 
minus the start of its series,
and so is transcendental.

$f_m(2)$
is $I_0(2)$
minus the start of its series,
where $I_0(x)$
is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.
I do not know if $I_0(2)$
is transcendendal,
but $J_0(1)$ is known to be,
so I would be willing to bet that
$all$ the $f_m(k)$
are transcendental.

I will now get an upper bound
on  $f_m(k)$
to aid in the computation of $F_m$.

$f_m(k) 
= \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n!)^k}
= \frac{1}{(m!)^k}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{m!}{n!}\right)^k
$.

If $n > m$,
$\frac{n!}{m!}
=\prod_{k=1}^{n-m} (m+k)
\ge (m+1)^{n-m}
$,
so
$f_m(k) 
\le \frac{1}{(m!)^k}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(m+1)^{n-m}}\right)^k
= \frac{1}{(m!)^k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(m+1)^{nk}}
= \frac{1}{(m!)^k}\frac{(m+1)^{-k}}{1-(m+1)^{-k}}
= \frac{1}{(m!)^k((m+1)^k-1)}
$.

Since the $f_m(k)$ are decreasing,
$|F_m| < f_m(1) 
< \frac{1}{m!m}
$.

This means that the error
in using the first $m$ terms in the product
is less than this bound.

This somehow seems
a more obvious result than I would like,
but I will have to leave it at this
since I do not see a more effective way of
estimating the sum.

Possibly some acceleration method could be used
to actually get more accurate estimates.

Comment: The individual interior series converge quickly, but since they converge to 1 as $k\to\infty$, your 'exterior' series is still only converging as the $\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ series for $\log 2$ does, i.e., terribly slowly (on the order of $n^{-1}$ for $n$ terms).

Comment: Good point. I will try to modify my answer to provide a better way of computing the result.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [general relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502160/can-the-exponential-function-be-reprsented-as-infinite-product/1102349#1102349)

$$a_1\cdot\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)a_n$$

with the partial products

$$a_n\equiv p_{n-1}:=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k!}\right),$$

for which it happens that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1=\frac{1}{n!},$$

I found the sum representation

$$p=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n!}\,{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k!}\right)$$

The first few terms are $1,1,1,\tfrac{1}{2}$, for a total of 3.5. It is very fastly converging, as the monotonically increasing $a_n$ are, by definition, bounded by $p<4$. The fourth term is already $\dfrac{a_4}{4!}\approx 0.1\dots$

Here you can now also find a simple approximation scheme using the expansion of ${\rm e}^1$.

Answer (score 4):

I've been intrested in products aswell (see my question) the methode i used was this one, i hope it helps.

$$\prod_{i=b}^c 1+a_i$$=
$$1+\sum_{i=b}^{c} (a_i)+$$
$$1/2!((\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i))^2-\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)^2$$
$$1/3!((\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i))^3-3\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)^2\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)+2\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)^3)$$
$$1/4!((\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i))^4-6(\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i))^2\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)^2+3(\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)^2)^2+8(\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)^3)\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)-6\sum_{i=b}^c (a_i)^4)$$

These are the refined strirling numbers, but i guess you get the pattern, i dont master the skills yet to write this more efficient down.