# Eulers number as infinite product

Tags: reference-request, products, eulers-number-e

On this page ([Exponential Function as an Infinite Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502160/exponential-function-as-an-infinite-product/653003#653003)) I saw Euler's number expressed as an infinite product as

$$e=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e_n+1}{e_n}=\frac{2}{1}.\frac{5}{4}.\frac{16}{15}.\frac{65}{64}.\frac{326}{325}.\frac{1957}{1956}. ...$$

I understand the proof given on that page, but where was this formula originally mentioned? Am looking to reference it in a paper I am writing but have not found any other mention of it online. Any help pinning it down would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question could have been a comment on that answer.

Comment: http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/E/e.html

Comment: @user91500 ... The end of §4 ... see the Postscipt version of it http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/E/e.ps